# Console application base template changed--how to change back?

Tags: c#, templates, console-application

I somehow changed my console application base template to

```
using System;

namespace x
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And now I cant find a .exe in my directories for newly created applications. I know you can create a new template, but I woiuld much rather restore the old one if possible.

Comment: "I can't find an EXE in my directories". Are you, by any chance, creating a .NET Core console application as opposed to a .NET Framework console application? .NET Core will generate a .dll instead of a .exe unless you publish for Windows.

Comment: Sorry, new to programming in general. How would I tell which one I am creating?

Comment: Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer and select properties. It will say "Target framework" and then indicate which one you're targeting.

Comment: Sorry again...I cant find it. The properties window is empty except for teh options on how to sort it.

Comment: Options on how to sort it? I don't think you have opened the properties window for the project. Alternative method: Click the "Project" menu at the top, look near the bottom and select "[Project name] Properties..."

Comment: It has a netcoreapp file, which suggests its from a .net core application. Are there any other ways to switch framework?

Comment: I have the properties window(the correct one) now. Thanks! However, my only framework options are .NET core 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0.

Comment: The simplest option is just to create a new solution/project and select "Console App (.NET Framework)"

Comment: That works too!. Thanks for all the help, it works now!

Answer (score -1):

Simply making a new application in Console App(.NET Framework) uses the correct template and makes a .exe file. Credit to John for the answer.